# Add text to span and make smooth height transition

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to add some long text to span and make it's height grow smoothly.

```
 $('span').text('Long long Long long Long long Long long Long long Long long Long long Long long Text').animate('height', 'slow')
```

Doesn't work

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hvZT/271/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify how large it is, and how large you want it to grow. Check this one out:

http://jsfiddle.net/6hvZT/273/

Here's where you specify the size it grows to:

```
$('.element').text(text).animate({'height':'150px'}, 'slow');
```

Also, specify the height of the element in its CSS.

Comment: what if I don't know new height?

Comment: Make a 'shadow' element that remains hidden, set the width to the same size, fill it with text at the same time, temporarily show it to gather the height and hide it again, then assign that height to the animation. Check:
http://jsfiddle.net/6hvZT/275/